# "In Gerichten einsetzen" oder "für Gerichte einsetzen"?

Tags: preposition, verb, vocabulary

Es gibt einen Satz: **In diesem Restaurant werden fast alle Teile von Tieren in Gerichten eingesetzt**. Meine Deutschlehrerin (Muttersprachlerin aus Hannover) hat gesagt, dass hier *für Gerichte* statt *in Gerichten* stehen muss, und hinzugefügt, dass es kein Regel dafür gibt und eher um Sprachgefühl geht. Ist die Option mit *in* hier gar nicht akzeptabel?

Comment: Ich würde "in Gerichten verwendet" sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn deine Deutschlehrerein sagt, dass es dafür keine Regel gibt, ist sie nicht sonderlich kompetent. Vielleicht solltest du dich nach einer besseren Deutschlehrerin umsehen.

Auf das Wesentliche verkürzt, sind das die beiden Möglichkeiten:

1. Alle Teile werden **in Gerichten** eingesetzt.
2. Alle Teile werden **in Gerichte** eingesetzt.

Der fett markierte Teil ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung, die von der Präposition *in* eingeleitet wird. Die Präposition *in* ist eine Wechselpräposition, die sich auf ein Substantiv bezieht, das sowohl im Dativ als auch im Akkusativ stehen darf. Dieses Substantiv ist hier das Wort *Gericht*, und das steht im Satz 1 im Dativ und im Satz 2 im Akkusativ. Daher sind beide Sätze grammatisch korrekt.

Aber sie bedeuten nicht dasselbe.

Wenn der Akkusativ verwendet wird, wird damit eine Bewegung ausgedrückt, deren Zielpunkt das Wort im Akkusativ ist:

> Leonie geht in das Haus.

Aus diesem Satz ist klar herauszulesen, dass Leonie vorher außerhalb des Hauses war, und dass sie durch Gehen in das Innere des Hauses gelangt.

Wenn man stattdessen den Dativ verwendet, ändert sich das:

> Leonie geht in dem Haus.

Aus diesem Satz lässt sich eindeutig herauslesen, dass Leonie während des Gehens die ganze Zeit im Haus ist. Sie verlässt es nicht und sie betritt es nicht. Vielleicht geht sie von einem Zimmer in ein anderes, oder sie geht z.B. in der Küche im Kreis. Aber was auch immer sie da macht, sie macht es ohne von außen zu kommen. Sie bewegt sich zwar, aber das Haus ist nicht das Ziel der Bewegung, sondern der Ort, an dem die Bewegung stattfindet. Und das ist genau die Funktion des Dativ bei Wechselpräpositionen. Der Dativ zeigt an, dass keine zielgerichtete Bewegung stattfinden. Entweder findet gar keine Bewegung statt, oder die Bewegung findet an dem genannten Ort statt, ohne diesen Ort von irgendwo her zu erreichen.

Aus diesem Grund kann man Wechselpräpositionen mit bestimmten Verben auch nur im Dativ verwenden:

> Leonie schläft in dem Haus. (korrekt)
> Leonie schläft in das Haus. (falsch)

Das Verb *schlafen* ist kein Bewegungsverb, daher kann ein Satz, in dem es verwendet wird, auch gar keine Bewegung ausdrücken. Der Akkusativ ist aber nur möglich, wenn es eine Bewegung gibt, die in diesem Fall im Inneren des Hauses endet. Daher ist hier nur der Dativ möglich.

Was bedeutet das nun für die Fragestellung?

1. **Alle Teile werden in Gerichten eingesetzt.**
   Das ist der Dativ. Das heißt: entweder keine Bewegung, oder eine Bewegung, die sich nur innerhalb der Gerichte abspielt.

   Das Verb *einsetzen* kann hier als Synonym für *verwenden* interpretiert werden:

   > Alle Teile werden in Gerichten **verwendet**.

   Das passt perfekt. Das Verb *verwenden* drückt keine Bewegung aus, und das harmoniert sehr gut mit dem Dativ.

   Das Verb *einsetzen* kann aber auch eine Bewegung bedeuten (*Der Künstler möchte einen Stein in das Mosaik einsetzen.*) Synonyme dafür wären *einfügen, einbauen* oder *hineingeben.* Weil eine solche Bewegung jedoch nicht innerhalb eines Gerichts stattfinden kann, sondern immer von außerhalb des Gerichts kommen muss, passt diese Bedeutung nicht mit dem Dativ zusammen. Aus diesem Grund ist dem Zuhörer auch völlig klar, dass das Verb *einsetzen* in der anderen Bedeutung (als Synonym von *verwenden*) gemeint sein muss.
2. **Alle Teile werden in Gerichte eingesetzt.**
   Das ist der Akkusativ. Das heißt, es findet hier eine Bewegung statt, und diese Bewegung kommt von außen und endet in dem Gericht.

   Weil eine Bewegung stattfindet, ist auch die Bedeutung *verwenden* ausgeschlossen und *einsetzen* muss als *einfügen/einbauen/hineingeben* interpretiert werden.

Die Interpretation *"alle Teile von Tieren werden in die Gerichte hineingegeben"* ist zwar durchaus eine mögliche Interpretation, aber das Wort *einsetzen* drückt aus, dass dieses Einsetzen an einem ganz bestimmten Ort innerhalb des Gerichts stattzufinden hat, so wie wenn man ein Puzzleteil in ein Puzzle einsetzt oder einen bunten Stein in ein Mosaik. Das macht man beim Kochen aber nicht, jedenfalls sicher nicht, wenn man von "allen Teilen von Tieren" spricht.

Daher ist der Akkusativ zwar nicht komplett falsch, aber eine sehr schlechte Wahl. Der Dativ ist die viel bessere Wahl.

Weil man im Fall des Dativ das mehrdeutige Verb *einsetzen* (entweder *verwenden* oder *einfügen*) durch das eindeutige Synonym *verwenden* ersetzen kann, ist der folgende Satz sogar noch besser:

> Alle Teile werden in Gerichten **verwendet**.

Aber auch das Wort *Gericht* ist mehrdeutig. Im vorliegenden Fall ist zwar klar, welche Bedeutung gemeint ist (nämlich: Speisen), aber ein Gericht ist auch ein Ort an dem Juristen (Richter, Anwälte usw.) ihrer Arbeit nachgehen. Besser wäre es, auch diese Mehrdeutigkeit zu vermeiden, und dann sieht der ganze Satz so aus:

> In diesem Restaurant werden fast alle Teile von Tieren **in Speisen verwendet**.

Comment: Wg. des Kontextes ist eine Mehrdeutigkeit nicht gegeben und daher auch kein Anlass, eine zu vermeiden. Der Empfehlung von "verwendet" schließe ich mich aber gerne an.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin ebenfalls Muttersprachler, und ich finde beide Versionen akzeptabel. "In Gerichten einsetzen" wirkt auf mich ein klein wenig holpriger als "für Gerichte einsetzen", aber noch längst nicht so sehr, dass man es korrigieren müsste.

Ich könnte mir eventuell noch vorstellen, dass "in Gerichten einsetzen" den Hörer auf eine falsche Spur locken könnte, weil man an die andere Bedeutung von "Gericht", nämlich im Sinne des Rechtswesen, denken könnte:

> Frau Dr. Müller wird als Richterin im hiesigen Gericht eingesetzt.

Aber auch das ist eine eher theoretische Möglichkeit.

Comment: Man könnte "für Gerichte einsetzen" aber auch so interpretieren, dass die Tiere beim Kochen helfen. Ich würde "einsetzen" hier überhaupt nicht verwenden (bzw. stattdessen "verwenden" verwenden).

Comment: @tofro Das finde ich ehrlich gesagt noch konstruierter als meinen Ansatz mit der Gerichtsbarkeit ;)

Comment: Nun ist es klar, vielen Dank!